# php fails loading xcache.so after recompile

Tags: php

I recompiled PHP 5.4.39 on my raspbian to include support for pthreads.
Everything works nice, even the pthreads, but every time I run a php script from commandline (and I guess it's the same if apache uses php), it says it's failing loading xcache.so:

> Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/xcache.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/xcache.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals

I recompiled php using this information: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-zts-support-on-ubuntu-14-04

Although php is running fine, I'd like to know what this message means and I'd like to solve it if possible.

Comment: you've got a library compiled against something that doesn't include `compiler_globals`. e.g. you've probably got a mishmash of original libaries and new ones from your own recompile.

Comment: how do i track this down and fix this. i sadly have no clue...

Comment: where does your extension come from (package manager or compiled from source or whatever) ?

Comment: the sources are downoaded using `apt-get source php5` like described in the link to the tutorial I posted in my original post.

Comment: Have you seen the following question (especially the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201013/error-failed-loading-opcache-so-opcache-so-undefined-symbol-compiler-globals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have PHP extensions enabled that were built against an old build of PHP itself. The proper solution is to remove the incorrectly linked PHP extensions and rebuild them.

I suggest you start with the XCache extension (`php5-xcache` package on Ubuntu). Remove it and rebuild it by following the steps in the tutorial you mention (simply replace `php5` with `php5-xcache`).

Most likely some other extensions will have issues too. Remove and rebuild them as well.

If you only followed the tutorial with `php5` itself, it's safe to say you'll need to remove and rebuild *all* extensions. That's all packages starting with `php5-`.

PS: Not all PHP extensions support thread-safety. If you're unable to build a certain extension, but don't need it anyway, Simply uninstall it.

PPS: XCache is an opcode cache. Make sure you don't enable multiple opcode caches at the same time. For example, don't enable XCache and OPcache (or APC) together, but choose one.

Comment: thanks for your insights. as the website running on my raspberry won't be accessed very often, i guess i don't need an opcode cache. i uninstalled xcache now and the message is gone. if the website behaviour gets significantly slower, i can still reinstall a threadsafe-compiled version of xcache (i'll do it like you suggested: do the tutorial and replace php5 with php-xcache).

Comment: btw: i guess xcache wasn't running anyway, am i right? ^^

Comment: The error can be boiled down to "Failed loading XCache", so you're right, XCache wasn't used :)

Answer (score 0):

In `php.ini` search for `zend_extension` , do a `sudo updatedb` in another terminal and then locate `xcache.so` and that's the path you should put in `php.ini`. If that doesn't solve it, you may be using incompatible xcache module. i.e. Using thread safe xcache with non thread safe php or vice versa.