# PHP Shown as text

Tags: php, apache, laravel, redis, debian

The fix is probably very easy but I spent 4 hours trying to find it..
This is my first time working with Laravel. Im setting it up on Debian 8.
All the modules that are needed for this to work are installed.
The problem is that the php is shown as text.

What I tried so far:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties

sudo apt-get install -y php5
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
sudo apt-get install -y php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install -y php5-curl
sudo apt-get install -y php5-gd
sudo apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install -y git-core
sudo apt-get install -y phpmyadmin
apt-get install unzip

curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | bash -
apt-get install --yes nodejs
apt-get install --yes build-essential

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5

wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make test
sudo make install
cd utils
sudo ./install_server.sh

Changed the document root here: /etc/apache2/sites-avialable
From DocumentRoot /var/www/html to DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

Added this to the apache config.
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf


/etc/redis/6379.conf
Uncommented:
#bind 127.0.0.1
bind 127.0.0.1

service redis_6379 restart
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Did you already put a file into `/var/www/html/public` to see if Apache is working?

Comment: Is the `apache2` restarted successfully? I see you missed out `sudo` when restarting its service

Comment: @GuyT Yes, that is the problem. http://prntscr.com/9k6bfl

Comment: @Raptor Yes I tried restarting using sudo.

Comment: Just put a simple `index.php` in the folder with `<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>` to check if Apache is started.

Comment: @GuyT http://prntscr.com/9k6c2k

Comment: So your problem is that Apache isn't working. Provide the error when you execute following command `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @GuyT [ ok ] Restarting web server: apache2.
There is no error.

Comment: Then probably your document root is wrong. Check this is out in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Comment: @GuyT http://prntscr.com/9k6dpg Thats where the file index.php is and it matches to what it is set to in apache config /var/www/html/public

Comment: Did you enable the site?

Comment: @GuyT 
Site 000-default already enabled

Comment: Alright, execute following command: `sudo a2enmod php5`(you can use `a2query -m php5` to check if the module is loaded) I guess you did not enable PHP on Apache. Afterwards restart apache.

Comment: @GuyT 
Output:
sudo a2enmod php5
Module php5 already enabled

a2query -m php5
There is more than one MPM loaded. Do not proceed due to undefined results.

Comment: Could you uninstall `libapache2-mod-php5`? That breaks your installation. From their documentation: `This package provides the PHP5 module for the Apache 2 webserver Please note that this package ONLY works with Apache's prefork MPM, as it is not compiled thread-safe.` And take a look at following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883646/apache-prefork-vs-worker-mpm

Comment: Use `a2query -M` to see MPM and `a2query -m` to check the enabled modules. Please post the output.

Comment: @GuyT The output is : There is more than one MPM loaded. Do not proceed due to undefined results

Comment: Then check which MPM modules are loaded. Did you already executed the `a2query -m`

Comment: To help you: use `ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm*` to check the enabled MPM and disable one of them (`a2dismod mpm_worker`)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a conf for your project in apache folder,
but before just go to the laravel folder and run:

```
php artisan serve
```

then click the link (probably http://localhost:8000)
and see if you get laravel main page.

If it succeeds, now lets create the apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName  EXAMPLE.COM
    DocumentRoot /PATH/TO/YOUR/LARAVEL/PUBLIC/FOLDER
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /PATH/TO/YOUR/LARAVEL/PUBLIC/FOLDER>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

place this file in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/YourProjectName.conf
```

now run this:

```
 sudo a2ensite YourProjectName.conf
```

and this

```
 sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9k6fia
The problem is that im not doing it localy. Its on a vds. When I try going to the vds ip:800 it throws an error.

Comment: I did all of the above. But get the same problem :(

Comment: sorry I dont know what are your server configurations so its hard to help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `composer update` or `composer install`? That seems to fix most of my headaches when Laravel spits out text. Had the same issue before but i can never remember exactly what fixes it

Comment: Ive done this:
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

And when I exec 'composer install' it asks for the json file.

Comment: I think composer needs to be in `usr/bin` and not in `usr/local/bin`, not sure if that's an ubuntu thing or just a composer thing in general. (edit, damn enter shortcut) also is there a `vendor` directory at the root of your laravel project?

(edit again) - There also needs to be a composer.json at the root of your laravel directory, the way i do it with new projects is i run `composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory}` which grabs everything including vendor